# transaction could not be decoded: could not recover secp256k1 key: calculated Rx is larger than curve P

Tags: solidity, truffle

I am getting following error while trying to compile solidity contract:

```
transaction could not be decoded: could not recover secp256k1 key: calculated Rx is larger than curve P
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, downgrading the version of **@truffle/hdwallet-provider** in package.json from 1.2.4 to 1.2.3 helped:

```
"@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "1.2.3",
```

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here, I was able to solve it following this answer [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/3940#issuecomment-804939546)

You need to downgrade `@truffle/hdwallet-provider` to version `1.0.40`